# HazelcastException: Cannot use EqualPredicate predicate with an array or a collection attribute

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am storing users and their locations in hazelcast. When i fire query on locations iam facing exception.

I am using hazelcast **3.12.1** version

i followed hazelcast's reference manual
https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#querying-in-collections-and-arrays

```
Predicate pagingPredicate = new PagingPredicate<String, User>(
            new SqlPredicate("userActive  AND ( locations=null OR  ( locations[any].country='India' AND locations[any].state='Telangana' AND locations[any].city='Hyderabad' ) )"), PRICE_COMPARATOR, 2);
        return usersMap.values(pagingPredicate)
```

and my PriceComparator.java

```
public class PriceComparator implements Comparator<Entry<String, User>>,
    Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -198157764684077461L;

    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<String, User> o1, Entry<String, User> o2) {
        return Double.compare(o2.getValue().getSalary().doubleValue(),
            o1.getValue().getSalary().doubleValue());
    }
}
```

I expect cache should return me with some values, but instead iam facing exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot use EqualPredicate predicate with an array or a collection attribute
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Finally issue got resolved.
This was an issue because of condition `locations=null`. When I replaced this condition with `locations.size=0` it worked fine.

I am unable to figured it out why `null` check on collection throws an exception??

If anyone has an answer please let me know